# Mostrar error en UITextField SWIFT XCODE

Tags: swift, xcode

Tengo la siguiente extension

```
private var rightViews = NSMapTable<UITextField, UIView>(keyOptions: NSPointerFunctions.Options.weakMemory, valueOptions: NSPointerFunctions.Options.strongMemory)
private var errorViews = NSMapTable<UITextField, UIView>(keyOptions: NSPointerFunctions.Options.weakMemory, valueOptions: NSPointerFunctions.Options.strongMemory)

        extension UITextField {
        // Add/remove error message
        func setError(_ string: String? = nil, show: Bool = true) {
            if let rightView = rightView, rightView.tag != 999 {
                rightViews.setObject(rightView, forKey: self)
            }



            // Remove message
            guard string != nil else {
                if let rightView = rightViews.object(forKey: self) {
                    self.rightView = rightView
                    rightViews.removeObject(forKey: self)
                } else {
                    self.rightView = nil
                }

                if let errorView = errorViews.object(forKey: self) {
                    errorView.isHidden = true
                    errorViews.removeObject(forKey: self)
                }

                return
            }

            // Create container
            let container = UIView()
            container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            // Create triangle
            let triagle = TriangleTop()
            triagle.backgroundColor = .clear
            triagle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            container.addSubview(triagle)

            // Create red line
            let line = UIView()
            line.backgroundColor = .red
            line.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            container.addSubview(line)

            // Create message
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = string
            label.textColor = .white
            label.numberOfLines = 0
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
            label.backgroundColor = .black
            label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250), for: .horizontal)
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            container.addSubview(label)

            // Set constraints for triangle
            triagle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
            triagle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15).isActive = true
            triagle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
            triagle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true

            // Set constraints for line
            line.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 3).isActive = true
            line.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: triagle.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            line.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            line.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

            // Set constraints for label
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: line.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

            if !show {
                container.isHidden = true
            }
            // superview!.superview!.addSubview(container)
    //        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.addSubview(container)

            self.addSubview(container)

            // Set constraints for container
            container.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: superview!.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
            container.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

            // Hide other error messages
            let enumerator = errorViews.objectEnumerator()
            while let view = enumerator!.nextObject() as! UIView? {
                view.isHidden = true
            }

            // Add right button to textField
            let errorButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
            errorButton.tag = 999
            errorButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_error"), for: .normal)
            errorButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.height, height: frame.size.height)
            errorButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(errorAction), for: .touchUpInside)
            rightView = errorButton
            rightViewMode = .always

            // Save view with error message
            errorViews.setObject(container, forKey: self)
        }
```

La cual me genera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual me lo coloca al final de la vista como se puede apreciar

lo que deseo es poder dejar cada error abajo de cada caja envez de ponerlo a lo ultimo de la view

Se que este problema esta aca

```
 self.addSubview(container)
```

Como podria yo modificar este extesion para que se coloque debajo de cada caja envez de colocarse debajo de la view, desde ya gracais

Comment: Talvéz probaste con [reglas de texto](https://medium.com/@ernesto.torres/validating-uitextfield-input-with-text-rules-79b16716154d)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria mejor que hicieras una custom class para tu TextField pero de esta forma te servirá, solo recuerda que cuando apliques las constraints agregar un padding de 15 al top del textfield previo.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


extension UITextField {

    func removeError () {
        self.layer.sublayers?.removeAll()
    }

    func setError(_ title : String) {
       setupErrorLayout()
        guard let label = self.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UILabel }) else { return }
        (label as? UILabel)?.text = title
    }

    func setupErrorLayout() {
        setupUnderline()
        setupTriangle()
        setupLabel()
    }

    func setupUnderline() {
        let bottomLine = CALayer()
        bottomLine.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: frame.height + 2, width: frame.width, height: 1)
        bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.borderStyle = .none
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)

    }


    func setupTriangle() {
        let bounds = CGRect.init(x: frame.width, y: frame.height + 3, width: 10, height: 10)
        let rad = bounds.size.width / 2
        let aSide = rad * sqrt(rad / 2) / 2
        let bSide = rad / 2
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: -rad))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: aSide, y: bSide))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: -aSide, y: bSide))
        bezierPath.close()
        let triangle = CAShapeLayer()
        triangle.path = bezierPath.cgPath
        triangle.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        triangle.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        triangle.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: frame.width - rad, y: frame.height)
        self.layer.addSublayer(triangle)
    }

    func setupLabel() {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: frame.height + 10, width: frame.width, height: 7))
        label.text = ""
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 8.0)
        label.textAlignment = .right
        self.addSubview(label)
    }

}

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect.init(x: 50, y: 50, width: 300, height: 50))

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white


        textField.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        textField.text = "Some text to evaluate"



        let set = UIButton(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100))
        set.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        set.backgroundColor = .green

        let unset = UIButton(frame: CGRect.init(x: 150, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100))
        unset.addTarget(self, action: #selector(unsetAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        unset.backgroundColor = .red

        view.addSubview(textField)
        view.addSubview(set)
        view.addSubview(unset)
        self.view = view
    }

    @objc func setAction(_ sender: Any) {
        textField.setError("Tienes algunos errores")
    }
    @objc func unsetAction(_ sender: Any) {
        textField.removeError()
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```